# query on Swagger openapi sample petstore

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-editor

I was looking into petstore sample api, modified it a bit with oneOf, anyOf etc,. yaml file is present at the end.

When I POST with the below request body which has Dog properties “bark” and “breed” to /pet, I get 200 ok.

```
{
  "id": 111,
  "name": "doggie",
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dogs"
  },
  "photoUrls": [
    "string"
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "status": "available",
   "bark": true,
   "breed": "Dingo"
}
```

But when I do GET /pet/{petId} with id 111, I don’t get Dog properties “bark” and “breed” back from the server. I get the below response without Dog properties.

```
{
  "id": 111,
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dogs"
  },
  "name": "doggie",
  "photoUrls": [
    "string"
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "status": "available"
}
```

The reason for not getting the Dog properties is because, https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore/tree/master/src/main/java/io/swagger/petstore/model does not have Dog. Is that correct?

```html
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Swagger Petstore - OpenAPI 3.0
  description: |-
    This is a sample Pet Store Server based on the OpenAPI 3.0 specification.  You can find out more about
    Swagger at [https://swagger.io](https://swagger.io). In the third iteration of the pet store, we've switched to the design first approach!
    You can now help us improve the API whether it's by making changes to the definition itself or to the code.
    That way, with time, we can improve the API in general, and expose some of the new features in OAS3.

    _If you're looking for the Swagger 2.0/OAS 2.0 version of Petstore, then click [here](https://editor.swagger.io/?url=https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.yaml). Alternatively, you can load via the `Edit > Load Petstore OAS 2.0` menu option!_
    
    Some useful links:
    - [The Pet Store repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore)
    - [The source API definition for the Pet Store](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore/blob/master/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml)
  termsOfService: http://swagger.io/terms/
  contact:
    email: apiteam@swagger.io
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
  version: 1.0.11
externalDocs:
  description: Find out more about Swagger
  url: http://swagger.io
servers:
  - url: https://petstore3.swagger.io/api/v3
tags:
  - name: pet
    description: Everything about your Pets
    externalDocs:
      description: Find out more
      url: http://swagger.io
paths:
  /pet:
    put:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Update an existing pet
      description: Update an existing pet by Id
      operationId: updatePet
      requestBody:
        description: Update an existent pet in the store
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
               #oneOf:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
                #- $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                 $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
                #oneOf:
                #- $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
                         
        '400':
          description: Invalid ID supplied
        '404':
          description: Pet not found
        '405':
          description: Validation exception
      security:
        - petstore_auth:
            - write:pets
            - read:pets
    post:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Add a new pet to the store
      description: Add a new pet to the store
      operationId: addPet
      requestBody:
        description: Create a new pet in the store
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              anyOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PetByAge'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PetByType'
          application/xml:
            schema:
              anyOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PetByAge'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PetByType'
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              anyOf:
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PetByAge'
                - $ref: '#/components/schemas/PetByType'
        required: true
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'          
            application/xml:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        '405':
          description: Invalid input
      security:
        - petstore_auth:
            - write:pets
            - read:pets
  /pet/findByTags:
    get:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Finds Pets by tags
      description: Multiple tags can be provided with comma separated strings. Use tag1, tag2, tag3 for testing.
      operationId: findPetsByTags
      parameters:
        - name: tags
          in: query
          description: Tags to filter by
          required: false
          explode: true
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'          
            application/xml:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        '400':
          description: Invalid tag value
      security:
        - petstore_auth:
            - write:pets
            - read:pets
  /pet/{petId}:
    get:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Find pet by ID
      description: Returns a single pet
      operationId: getPetById
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          description: ID of pet to return
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '200':
          description: successful operation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                  anyOf:
                    #- $ref: '#/components/schemas/PetByAge'
                    #- $ref: '#/components/schemas/PetByType'
                    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
                    - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
                  discriminator: 
                    propertyName: petType
            application/xml:
              schema:
                oneOf:
                  #- $ref: '#/components/schemas/Cat'
                  - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Dog'
        '400':
          description: Invalid ID supplied
        '404':
          description: Pet not found
      security:
        - api_key: []
        - petstore_auth:
            - write:pets
            - read:pets
    post:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Updates a pet in the store with form data
      description: ''
      operationId: updatePetWithForm
      parameters:
        - name: petId
          in: path
          description: ID of pet that needs to be updated
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
        - name: name
          in: query
          description: Name of pet that needs to be updated
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: status
          in: query
          description: Status of pet that needs to be updated
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '405':
          description: Invalid input
      security:
        - petstore_auth:
            - write:pets
            - read:pets
    delete:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Deletes a pet
      description: delete a pet
      operationId: deletePet
      parameters:
        - name: api_key
          in: header
          description: ''
          required: false
          schema:
            type: string
        - name: petId
          in: path
          description: Pet id to delete
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int64
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid pet value
      security:
        - petstore_auth:
            - write:pets
            - read:pets
components:
  schemas:
    Category:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 1
        name:
          type: string
          example: Dogs
      xml:
        name: category
    Tag:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
        name:
          type: string
      xml:
        name: tag
    Dog:   
      allOf: 
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        - type: object
          # all other properties specific to a `Dog`
          properties:
            bark:
              type: boolean
            breed:
              type: string
              example: Husky
    Cat:     
      allOf: 
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        - type: object
          # all other properties specific to a `Cat`
          properties:
            hunts:
              type: boolean
            age:
              type: integer
              example: 25
    Pet:
      required:
        - name
        - photoUrls
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 10
        name:
          type: string
          example: doggie
        category:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/Category'
        photoUrls:
          type: array
          xml:
            wrapped: true
          items:
            type: string
            xml:
              name: photoUrl
        tags:
          type: array
          xml:
            wrapped: true
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Tag'
        status:
          type: string
          description: pet status in the store
          enum:
            - available
            - pending
            - sold
      xml:
        name: pet
    AnotherObject:   
      allOf: 
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        - type: object
          # all other properties specific to a `Dog`
          properties:
            bark:
              type: boolean
            breed:
              type: string
              enum: [Dingo, Husky, Retriever, Shepherd]
              example: Husky
    YetAnotherObject:     
      allOf: 
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        - type: object
          # all other properties specific to a `Cat`
          properties:
            hunts:
              type: boolean
            age:
              type: integer
              example: 20
    PetByAge:
      type: object
      properties: 
        age: 
          type: integer
        nickname: 
          type: string
      required:
        - age
          
    PetByType:
      type: object
      properties:
        pet_type:
          not:
            type: integer
          type: string
          enum: [Cat, Dog]
        hunts:
          type: boolean
      required: 
        - pet_type
  requestBodies:
    Pet:
      description: Pet object that needs to be added to the store
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
        application/xml:
          schema:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/Pet'
  securitySchemes:
    petstore_auth:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        implicit:
          authorizationUrl: https://petstore3.swagger.io/oauth/authorize
          scopes:
            write:pets: modify pets in your account
            read:pets: read your pets
    api_key:
      type: apiKey
      name: api_key
      in: header
```